# What code should I add to make x start at 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to make graph with matplotlib, and my graph should start from 1 not 0, But I don't know how to do. I can do this by writing all figures in x_coords and y_coords, but I want to know the code I can use while I use `f = open()`. Sorry that I'm not fluent in English

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

avg_prices = []
labels = (i for i in range(1, 53))

f = open('C:/1994_Weekly_Gas_Averages.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    avg_prices.append(float(line))

plt.plot(avg_prices, 'o--', label=labels)

plt.title('1994 Weekly Gas Prices')
plt.xlabel('Weeks')
plt.ylabel('Average prices')
plt.grid()
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 60, 10))
plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 1.17, 0.025))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the corresponding x coordinate in before the y coordinate.

```
x = list(range(1,53))
plt.plot(x, avg_prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

`labels = (i for i in range(0, 53))` should work. `range` function will start from the first parameter and run al the way till the n-1 of the second parameter.

`labels = (i for i in range(0, 53))` will give labels from `0.....52`

`labels = (i for i in range(1, 53))` will give labels from `1.....52`

`labels = (i for i in range(1, 54))` will give labels from `1.....53`

`labels = (i for i in range(0, 54))` will give labels from `0.....53`